# PHP: How to get data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

If I log in with my email and password in table 'students', how can I get the data from the table 'data' where the emailadresses match?

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `student_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `studygroup_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `applied_courses` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `study_results` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: What does "og in with my email and password in table 'students'" mean? Is the email stored in a session, or do you want an SQL-query where a specified email and password return not only the corresponding data from `students`, but also the rows where `data.email = students.email`?

Comment: Do you know how to store the login user's username?

Comment: if you have student id in your `data` table then just match the email into the `students` table and get the id from it, and match that `student_id` into your `data` table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easy answer would just be to execute a query like

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE email = '$emailAddress'
```

Where $emailAddress is the email address that has been used to log in.

But you should really think about your schema design. Perhaps go and read some books/tutorials on the basics and there are a number of possible issues with what you have. You should probably have a numeric primary key on your "students" table and reference this as a foreign key in your other table. You should also think about renaming the second table. "Data" doesn't really describe what it does; everything (or very nearly) in a database is data! Plus all your id columns are varchars. Unless you have alphanumeric ids you should make these columns the correct type for the data they hold.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify question.  Where's the password coming from?  A script in PHP?

SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `student`.email = "$my_email" AND `student`.password = "$my_password"

Answer (score 0):

Students table should also contain the student_id

```
alter table student add column student_id int auto_increment primary key
```

then the query

```
select a.email, a.password,b.studentgroup_id, b.applied_course,b.student_result
from student a inner join 
data b 
on a.student_id=b.student_id
```

Comment: It's not very useful to provide a and b as identifier. Please don't give such advice to unexperienced developers.Using s and d respectively isn't a single keystroke more but readable way better. Especially when queries evolve and get more complex over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to confirm login and get data in one query, use a LEFT JOIN, which in the following example will give you a result from the `students` table, even if there is nothing in the `data` table for that email address.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `students` 
  LEFT JOIN `data` ON `students`.`email` = `data`.`email` 
  WHERE `students`.`password` = '" . $password . "' 
  AND `students`.`email` = '" . $email. "'";
```

Note: if there are multiple rows in the `data` table for the email address, each row will be returned and will contain identical `student.password` and `student.email` values.